# file is not being completely copied

Tags: clojure, copy

`file1.gif` is `637.8 kB`. A `file2.gif` is created but stops at `36 bytes`.

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])
(io/copy "/var/project-dir/uploads/file1.gif" 
         (io/file "/var/project-dir/uploads/file2.gif"))
```

Any idea what could be going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code inserts the string "/var/project-dir/uploads/file1.gif" into the destination file. You need to provide the actual source of the data:

```
(io/copy (io/file "/var/project-dir/uploads/file1.gif") 
         (io/file "/var/project-dir/uploads/file2.gif"))
```

Comment: I misinterpreted `Input may be an InputStream, Reader, File, byte[], or String.`; could've sworn I tried this answer a few minutes ago.

Comment: My clue was that your output file size was suspiciously close in size to the string you provided as an argument.